# retarget href after click function relocation

Tags: jquery

When a link is clicked, the following code finds the content of the .body for the given link, and displays it. The code works perfectly as expected.

```
$(document).on('click','.mails_show',function(){
    var mID = '#'+$(this).attr('data-show');
    if(mID == '#')return false;                
        $("#mail_body").html($(mID).find('.body').html());    
    return false;            
});
```

However after this code runs, I need to search for any hrefs in the #mail_body and redirect them to a tracking link

```
$("#mail_body a").click(function() {
    window.open('/trackinglink.php', "_blank", '', false);
});
```

The problem seems to be that after .body is moved to #mail_body jquery doesn't seem to find any a tags. How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : use `on` to bind click event as mail body is getting added dynamically

```
$(document).on("click","#mail_body a", function() {
    window.open('/trackinglink.php', "_blank", '', false);
});
```

Comment: happy to help you :), you can accept the answer if find useful

Comment: just had wait for 10 min to pass :)